# \documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62} figure* ALWAYS gets its own page

Tags: floats, page-breaking, aastex

I'm using

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}

\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}% hyperref works too
\urlstyle{same}  % (sf also works, for something more subtle than tt)
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[]{units} % Provides \nicefrac

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.10}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.9}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{4pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{graphicx}       % Use pdf, png, jpg, or eps§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
```

And floats that are 2 columns wide -- e.g. -

```
\begin{figure*}[th!]
\vspace*{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{{{./Metallicity_z_12.0-brightRed}}} 
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{{{./Metallicity_z_9.0-brightRed}}} 
\caption{Locations of Pop III-bright galaxies. \label{fig:p3brightLocs}}
\end{figure*}
```

ALWAYS get their own page. How can I stop this? I can't

Comment: Hi, I work for the AAS Journals. Using the standard template file distributed with v6.2, I can only reproduce what you find if I include the \usepackage{dblfloatfix}. Commenting that out allows the text to flow around the figure just fine. Leaving it in causes the page breaks you describe. We do not support the dblfloatfix package.

Comment: btw, we already import hyperref with aastex62. You should use `\hypersetup{breaklinks,colorlinks,allcolors=blue}` instead

Comment: BTW, figure* does not support [h] or [h!] (although h! is actually htp).

Comment: Note that `\begin{figure*}[th!]` is the same a `\begin{figure*}[t!]` so prevents the float appearing on a float page so greatly increases the chance of it going to the end of the document, also it is odd to have preamble commands setting parameters such as `\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.10}` if you use `!` (which means ignore the parameter) or `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.9}` if you use `[ht]` which means do not allow float pages

Comment: Thank @Gus... perfect. I should have tried that. ... and thx John and David -- I was just trying everything (even tho I know h! isn't supposed to work) to try and get my text to flow!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Gus, don't use

```
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
```

with `aastex62` ... It causes floats with `figure*` to always be placed on their own page.